# Unexpected behavior with VS Code and Chrome. Chrome shows every time in the foreground when I update some little code on VS Code

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm having a small strange behavior with Visual Studio Code and Google Chrome when I'm debugging my Vue JS project.

Formerly, when I updated some code on VS Code, my Chrome updated automatically in the background (expected behavior), but now, after the last update, every time I update my code on VS Code, even a little modification (e.g. add a new word in a phrase), Chrome shows/appears on my screen in the foreground (unexpected behavior).

This unexpected behavior is disturbing me, because I need to close the Chrome every time I do a new modification on my code.

Would anyone know what can be happening? I've already looked for it on the internet, but I was not able to figure out anything to help me.

My VS Code configuration:

```
Version: 1.33.1
Commit: 51b0b28134d51361cf996d2f0a1c698247aeabd8
Date: 2019-04-11T08:20:22.771Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-48-generic
```

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you in advance.